# javascript: pulling items out of one array and putting them in another

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got two arrays, `numbers` and `picks`. `numbers` contains a series of numbers, and `picks` is currently empty. I want to pull N values out of `numbers`, and put them in `picks`. So I've tried `picks.push(numbers.splice(idx,1));`, where `idx` is a random number between 0 and the highest index in `numbers`. This doesn't *seem* to be working. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: splice returns an array, not a value.

Comment: Have you tried debugging or putting some console logs to see what happens? Also... can you share your code with us?

Comment: `console.log(numbers.splice(idx,1))` will help you debug step by step

Comment: `[].push.apply(picks, numbers.splice(idx, 1));`

Comment: Do the move N times like `for (var i=0; i<N; i++) picks.push(numbers.shift())`, see that it works and then move to your real problems before coming back to this.

Comment: @raina77ow - that seems like a much better answer than the one currently posted, which doesn't work with anything more than one single value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `splice` returns an array, you only need a small tweak, to retrieve the first (and only) item in this new array:

```
picks.push(numbers.splice(idx,1)[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This was exactly what I needed. But I'm not quite I understand *why* it works. Can you explain further? 
Cheers!

Comment: `splice` returns an array - in this case, an array with one item. `push` accepts an item to be added to an array - specifically, a number. So you want the first item in the resulting array, not the array itself, to pass into the `push` function.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as many others said, Array.splice() returns an array (with the elements ordered to remove from the source array). So you can either use the fact that you always take a single number from it, as in @JoeEnos answer, or employ more universal form:

```
[].push.apply(picks, number.splice(idx, 1)); 
// replace 1 with any other positive number, and it still works
```

---

Still, it looks to me you're just trying to reimplement [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) algorithm. Here, the key is using not `splice` (as reordering huge arrays might cause a performance hit), but exchange the chosen element with the one at the end of the source array. Here's how it can be done:

```
var source   = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
var shuffled = Array(source.length);
var i, j, len;
for (i = 0, len = shuffled.length; i < len; ++i) {
  j = Math.random() * (i + 1)|0;
  if (i !== j) {
    shuffled[i] = shuffled[j];
  }
  shuffled[j] = source[i];
}
console.log(shuffled);
```

Here's [eval.in demo](https://eval.in/512034) to play with.